# using delphi touch gestures for image viewer

Tags: image, delphi, touch, gestures, viewer

I just started to work with delphi touch gestures. Because I have never done anything with multitouch, I want to first create a small image viewer with move/zoom/rotate functionality. 
I have placed a TImage on a TScrollBox. Actually, when the onGesture method of the image is called, EventInfo is read to decided which gesture was recognized to show it in a message box. Like that, all of the gestures can be recognized but the pan gesture. I think this one is needed to move a picture when it's zoomed in by tapping and moving it. What am I doing wrong? 
And is there a useful framework with built-in zoom/rotate functionality maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbars already take care of panning.